# How to deal with closure scoping in groovy code in the pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I've a method named "runTest", which is responsible for running certain tests in the pipeline, and I've another method named "chooseTest" which is responsible for parsing param and appending those tests in a map. In "chooseTest" method I also have switch-case which checks for which test needs to be appended in the map. How would I use closure to call "runTest" method in that switch-case so that I can call it after I break out of the loop (for checking each test).

I've tried making "runTest" itself a closure, but I ran into "Method too long error" which was a headache to debug, so I tried creating a closure variable in each of those if statement cases. I ran into scoping issue which doesn't allow me to run those closure calls outside of the for-loop. I have attached example of my approaches below

```
// INSIDE of chooseTest method-->

switch (testName){
      case 'aTest':
           def runATest = {runTest('aTest')}
           break
      case 'bTest':
           def runBTest = {runTest('bTest')}
           break
}

runAtest.call()

//This is where I ran into scoping issue

//Another approach I tried (saw this approach elsewhere, not sure if this is even the correct approach syntactically)

def runTests = []
switch (testName){
      case 'aTest':
           runTests << {-> runTest('aTest')}
           break
      case 'bTest':
           runTests << {-> runTest('bTest')}
           break
}

runTests.each
```

I expect the closure to not have scoping errors, and when i call it outside of the case statement it invoke the chooseTest method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I am such a noobie guys, I could just define like such.

```
def runAtest

switch(test){
    case 'atest':
        runAtest = {print('you a noob')}
        break
}
```